# SQL Server- Ways to avoid CXPACKET wait

Tags: sql-server

This might seem trivial but I would like to know how exactly the CXPACKET wait can be avoided by using proper indexing techniques?

Comment: It's not trivial, it's too broad. CXPACKET means the server isn't utilizing parallelism properly. This *could* be caused by excessive scans (and an index might help turn it into a seek) but when scans are a concern, I/O and execution times are far more pressing than CXPACKET waits. Usually you worry about CXPACKET waits once you've solved any other problems, and by that time indexing is probably not what will resolve such waits. Do you have an actual problem involving CXPACKET waits and nothing else? If so, what makes you think indexing is the solution?

Comment: @JeroenMosert What exactly does it specify when you mention that an "Index might help turn it into a Seek"?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [T] WHERE X = 1`. If T has 1 million rows and there is exactly one where `X = 1`, then without an index, you may get a parallel index scan that shows CXPACKET waits if the server doesn't balance the load properly. With an index, you will get a seek that immediately retrieves the row with no waits at all. But the CXPACKET waits would not be the obvious symptom -- the excessive I/O and execution time would be.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: it *could* also just mean that SQL Server **is** using parallelism, and not all parallel threads return at the exact same time .....

Comment: See Paul Randal's excellent blog posts on this: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/sql-performance/knee-jerk-wait-statistics-cxpacket and https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/cxpacket/

Comment: @marc_s: that is what I mean by "not utilizing parallelism properly". Admittedly it's unfair to the engine to demand it never lets these things happen (that's impossible) but I have seen quite a few instances of CXPACKET waits caused by deficient load balancing, which gets worse the more processors the server has.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: ok - to me, that *is* using parallelism properly - the load just isn't distributed 100% perfectly amongst multiple worker threads - but that's really not a huge issue (most of the time)

Comment: @marc_s: as always with such things, mileages can vary. :-) Nothing more frustrating than seeing your query chug along while the last 4 of the 64 cores your server has are finishing up the query... with no chance of the remainder getting rebalanced as necessary. (Again, this is not entirely fair to the engine and it's easy to judge code from the sidelines, obviously.) I will grant that cases of *excessive* parallelism (where the load is wildly misdistributed because it would be better off sequential) are likelier culprits of CXPACKET waits.

Comment: I upvoted marc_s post because we cannot say "CXPACKET means the server isn't utilizing parallelism properly". CXPACKET is **always **presented if parallelism is used, and even when the work is ideally distributed between the threads, the thread 0 (coordinator) is always accumulate this wait because it's just waiting other threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should examing your queries that perform large scans. If those scans are caused by lack of indexes (when you have selective enough predicates but server does perform scan) you can avoid scans creating appropriate indexes. But if you are reading all the data, for example, every night we are loading the entire database reading all the tables from another database (OLTP, restored from another server), denormalizing data, and we peform full table scans anyway, we cannot avoid CXPACKET wait because the only option we have is to turn off parallelism at all but it will slow down our loading. So it's just there and the server has no problem with it. We just has this wait as top 1 at our server but it's perfectly well